# Formulário abrindo outro formulário dentro de um splitcontainer

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um formulário principal dividido por um `splitcontaniner`.
Quando clico em um botão do `panel1`, um formulário é carregado no `panel2`.

```
    private void btnCadastrarConta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stcMenuPrincipal.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
        frmCadastroConta formulario = new frmCadastroConta();
        formulario.TopLevel = false;
        formulario.AutoScroll = true;
        stcMenuPrincipal.Panel2.Controls.Add(formulario);
        formulario.Show();
    }
```

Esse formulário(frmCadastroConta) que foi carregado no `panel2` possui um `button` que exibe outro formulário(`frmInformacoesAdicionais`).

Como faço para o `frmInformacoesAdicionais` ser carregado no `panel2` no lugar do `frmCadastroConta`?

Uso **C#**, **Net 3.5**.

Comment: Você já tentou fazer o mesmo procedimento que fez para exibir o `frmCadastroConta` para exibir o `frmInformacoesAdicionais`?

Comment: Até tentei cara, não deu certo. Porém, eu fiz uma gambiarra. Botei o split do meu menu principal como public e adaptei o código. Terias outra maneira?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode **remover** o **frmCadastroConta** e **adicionar**  o **frmInformacoesAdicionais** do mesmo modo que fez para adicionar o **frmCadastroConta**.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um objeto referente ao outro form antes de entrar nesse método do clique do botão, daí, pra evitar memory leak, ce apaga esse form2 que tá dentro do form1 e cria o form3 no lugar do form2 no método do botão desse form2.

ce colocaria lá, por exemplo:

```
TForm3 form3 = new TForm3();
form3.TopLevel = false;
form1.panel2.Controls.Add(form3);
form3.Show();
Close();
```

Assim, seria criado o form3, mas o form2 seria retirado da memória. Se por acaso isso não for o que ce precisa, se precisar 'esconder' o form2, basta fazer a criação do form3 e a chamada dele dentro do botão do form2, fazendo um Hide nesse form2.

```
TForm3 form3 = new TForm3();
form3.TopLevel = false;
form1.panel2.Controls.Add(form3);
form3.Show();
Hide();
```

Apesar de dessa forma fazer seu programa ocupar mais memória, requerer mais processamento, pra casos de testes ele até serve.

Answer (score 0):

> **Nota:** sei que a pergunta é antiga, porém creio que a resposta possa ajudar outros usuários.

### Introdução

Uma solução para essa questão seria utilizar [**Eventos**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/awbftdfh.aspx), os eventos permitem que classes ou objetos notifiquem outras classes ou objetos que uma certa ação foi realizada, possibilitando que quem assinou esses eventos possam realizar alguma tarefa relacionada ao mesmo.

Utilizamos eventos frequentemente, um exemplo básico seria o evento `Click` do componente `Button`, que possibilita que façamos algo quando um botão é clicado.

### Códigos

Montei um cenário igual ao que você informou, defini o nome do `Form` principal como `frmPrincipal`:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App.Teste
{
    public partial class frmPrincipal : Form
    {
        public frmPrincipal()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnCadastrarConta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stcMenuPrincipal.Panel2.Controls.Clear();
            frmCadastroConta formulario = new frmCadastroConta();
            formulario.TopLevel = false;
            formulario.AutoScroll = true;
            formulario.NextForm += new frmCadastroConta.NextFormEventHandler(formulario_NextForm); // assina o evento
            stcMenuPrincipal.Panel2.Controls.Add(formulario);
            formulario.Show();
        }

        // método que irá tratar o evento
        private void formulario_NextForm(object source, string name)
        {
            ((Form)source).Close();
            if (name == "frmInformacoesAdicionais")
            {
                frmInformacoesAdicionais formulario = new frmInformacoesAdicionais();
                formulario.TopLevel = false;
                formulario.AutoScroll = true;
                stcMenuPrincipal.Panel2.Controls.Add(formulario);
                formulario.Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No `frmCadastroConta`, criei o botão `btnInformacoesAdicionais` que irá disparar o evento para carregar o `frmInformacoesAdicionais`:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace App.Teste
{
    public partial class frmCadastroConta : Form
    {

        public delegate void NextFormEventHandler(object source, string name);
        public event NextFormEventHandler NextForm;

        public frmCadastroConta()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnInformacoesAdicionais_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            OnNextForm("frmInformacoesAdicionais");
        }

        public virtual void OnNextForm(string name)
        {
            // verifica se o evento possui algum assinante
            if (NextForm != null)
                NextForm(this, name);
        }
    }
}
```

O `frmInformacoesAdicionais` não possui nada de especial, só criei um `Form` com um `Label` para identificá-lo.

### Explicações

O `Form` que irá gerar o evento é o `frmCadastroConta`, e o que irá receber (assinar) o evento é o `frmPrincipal`, ou seja, o `frmCadastroConta` irá notificar o `frmPrincipal` através do evento `NextForm` que um novo `Form` deve ser carregado.

Essas linhas abaixo possibilitam a utilização de eventos:

```
public delegate void NextFormEventHandler(object source, string name);
public event NextFormEventHandler NextForm;

...

public virtual void OnNextForm(string name)
{
    // verifica se o evento possui algum assinante
    if (NextForm != null)
        NextForm(this, name);
}
```

Declarado um [**Delegate**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/900fyy8e.aspx), o próprio evento e um método para chamar o evento.

> **Observação:** na declaração do `delegate` você pode informar os parâmetros que achar necessário, eu adicionei o `source` para identificar qual objeto gerou o evento e o `name` para identificar qual `Form` carregar.
>
> **Observação 2:** o nome do delegate, do evento e do método do evento (considere a utilização do prefixo `On` como uma boa prática para esse caso) é você que escolhe.

Feito isso você deve assinar o evento no `frmPrincipal` como mostra a linha:

```
formulario.NextForm += new frmCadastroConta.NextFormEventHandler(formulario_NextForm);
```

> **Observação:** você pode definir o nome que achar melhor para o seu método, não se esquecendo de declará-lo com os mesmos parâmetros do `delegate`.

O método `formulario_NextForm` irá tratar o evento gerado, que nesse caso irá fechar o `Form` que enviou o evento e carregar o `Form` passado pelo parâmetro `name`.

### Conclusão

A utilização de **Eventos** nesse caso, deixa seu código mais limpo e organizado, ficando livre de "gambiarras".

### Referências

[Comunicação entre Forms em .NET](http://www.devmedia.com.br/comunicacao-entre-forms-em-net/24839)
[C# - Eventos](http://www.macoratti.net/12/06/c_event1.htm)
[Como realizar e cancelar a assinatura de eventos (Guia de Programação em C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms366768.aspx)