# Habilitar KeyPress em Panel C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, panel

Tenho uma aplicação e ela funciona assim.

Tenho um codigo para criar `TextBox` dinamicamente quando a quantidade máxima de letras na `TextBox1` for 2.

Aqui está o código:

```csharp
private void VerificaTextBox(int contador)
{           
   foreach (Object item in Controls)
   {
      if (item is TextBox)
      {
          if (((TextBox)item).Text == null || ((TextBox)item).Text == "")
          {
              ((TextBox)item).KeyPress += delegate
              {
                  contador++;
                  if (contador >= 2)
                  {
                      Point p = new Point();
                      p = ((TextBox)item).Location;
                      TextBox nova = new TextBox();
                      nova.Name = "pagina" + 1;
                      nova.Multiline = true;
                      nova.Height = 294;
                      nova.MaxLength = 2;
                      nova.Width = 601;
                      // Anchor the button to the bottom right corner of the form
                      nova.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Top);
                      nova.Location = new Point(((TextBox)item).Location.X, ((TextBox)item).Location.Y + ((TextBox)item).Height + 20);
                      this.panel1.Controls.Add(nova);
```

Este Código funciona perfeitamente quando a `textbox1` não está dentro do `Panel1`.

A `textBox1` tem que ficar dentro do `Panel1` e o código funcionar, só que ele não está funcionando por que o `Panel` não tem `KeyPress` como posso solucionar isso. Sem usar o `KeyPress` da Form?

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade até existe existe o evento [`KeyPress()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.keypress.aspx)  para o `Panel` porém não é destinado a ser usado no seu código.

Veja um exemplo:

```
public void MyKeyPressEventHandler(Object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Fazer algo aqui
}

....  
...
(panel1 as Control).KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(MyKeyPressEventHandler);
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2132163/1608936)

Ao invés de tentar capturar a tecla pressionada no `Panel`, você pode verificar a quantidade de caracteres digitados no `TextBox1` e assim criar outro `TextBox` dinamicamente. No evento `TextChanged()` do `TextBox1` você pode fazer:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text.Length == 2)
            {
                // Fazer algo aqui
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Se entendi corretamente, seu problema está no `foreach (Object item in Controls)`. Quando você usa somente o *Controls*, você está pegando a coleção de controles do seu formulário, como o *TextBox* está dentro do *Panel*, ele não aparece, para pegar os controles do seu *Panel* utilize `foreach (Object item in this.panel1.Controls)`. Considere a utilização do evento *TextChanged* conforme sugerido na outra resposta.

Caso você ache necessário, consulte [esse link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42848/18327) para obter algumas informações sobre eventos e [esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47935/18327) que fala sobre *cast*.