# Qual a diferença entre um cast explícito e o operador as?

Tags: c#, .net, operadores, cast

Sempre quando realizo a conversão de um objeto para um tipo específico, utilizo um *cast* explícito, por exemplo:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBoxTemp = (TextBox)sender;
    MessageBox.Show("Você digitou: " + textBoxTemp.Text);
}
```

Consigo fazer a mesma coisa utilizando o operador *as*, dessa maneira:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBoxTemp = sender as TextBox;
    MessageBox.Show("Você digitou: " + textBoxTemp.Text);
}
```

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre as duas abordagens, quando devo usar uma ou outra e se existe alguma diferença de desempenho entre elas.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

O cast explicito lança exceção se o objeto não for do tipo.

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBoxTemp = (TextBox)sender;  // lança exceção se não for TextBox... InvalidCastException (eu acho que esse é o nome)
    MessageBox.Show("Você digitou: " + textBoxTemp.Text);
}
```

É usado quando você tem quase certeza absoluta que o tipo está correto... não sendo permitido usar o método em questão `textBox1_Leave` para qualquer outro tipo de objeto passado em `sender`.

O operador `as` não lança exceção, e retorna null caso o objeto não seja do tipo.

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBoxTemp = sender as TextBox; // não lança exceção
    MessageBox.Show("Você digitou: " + textBoxTemp.Text); // se não for do tipo, então vai lançar exceção aqui, NullPointerException
}
```

A forma correta de usar o operador `as` é testando se o retorno é nulo ou não, para não correr o risco de lançar uma exceção genérica, tal como a que ocorreria (exemplificado acima).

Correto:

```
    TextBox textBoxTemp = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBoxTemp != null)
        MessageBox.Show("Você digitou: " + textBoxTemp.Text);
    else
        // fazer algo quando for nulo
```

### Sobrecarga do cast

É possível sobrecarregar o operador de cast explícito somente. O `as` não pode ter o seu comportamento alterado.

Isso quer dizer que de vez em quando, o cast explícito está fazendo mais coisas do que se parece:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static explicit operator int(MyClass x)
    {
        return x.GetValor(); // fazendo uma operação qualquer no cast
    }
}
```

E em algum outro lugar, ao fazer o cast de `MyClass` para `int`, na verdade vai se chamar o método acima:

```
var x = (int)myClass; // cast sobrecarregado
```

### Operador `as`

O operador `as` só pode ser usado para converter para um tipo anulável. Não é possível usar um tipo não anulável no operando da direita. Ou seja, qualquer classe ou `Nullable<T>`.

valido: `1 as int?`; `obj as UmaClasse`

inválido:

```
object num = 1;
int num2 = num as int; // inválido
```

Comment: Interessante "quase certeza absoluta" :D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Quer dizer quase 100%... o que pode ser 99%, ou então 98%. Sendo que os 1% ou 2% de incerteza sobre o tipo, a partir do momento que se usa o cast, gera uma exceção clara.

Comment: Só quis fazer referencia ao [pleonasmo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qbm2w_T4laY). :D

Comment: Ahh tá... é que pensei que não estivesse claro. Bem que agora eu estou reparando a carinha feliz. =D

Answer (score 6):

Além das explicações já dadas de que cast (`(TextBox)sender`) lança exceção enquanto **as** (`sender as TextBox`) retorna *null* caso os tipos não sejam compatíveis, duas observações:

#### Usar um ou outro não se trata apenas de evitar exceção, mas sim de revelar intenção

```
TextBox textBoxTemp = (TextBox)sender;
```

O código acima diz que ele não admite que `sender` não seja um `TextBox`. Se não for, que se exploda, que uma exceção seja lançada e que seja capturada por quem estiver interessado, ou que quebre o aplicativo, porque o código ao redor só me interessa se `sender` for de fato um `TextBox`.

Já este código:

```
TextBox textBoxTemp = sender as TextBox;
```

está me dizendo que é perfeitamente aceitável que `sender` não seja um `TextBox`, e que eu tenho um plano para as duas situações. Neste caso, como já explicado, faz todo sentido que exista um teste `textBoxTemp != null` antes de sair usando esta variável.

#### Enquanto o cast pode provocar uma conversão de fato, "as" faz apenas *boxing/unboxing*

Se houvesse uma conversão de usuário implementada no objeto `sender`, o uso do **as** não ativaria esta conversão. O **as** pode apenas retornar um tipo cuja compatibilidade tiver sido definida pela hierarquia do objeto, seja por herança ou por implementação de interface.

Não seria errado dizer também, para efeito de simplicidade, que enquanto o operador **cast**, exemplo: `(TextBox)sender`, pode ser usado para conversão explícita de tipos, o operador **as**, exemplo `sender as TextBox`, pode ser usado para obter uma representação polimórfica do objeto, não havendo conversão de fato.

Answer (score 6):

## *Cast* clássico

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    TextBox textBoxTemp = (TextBox)sender;
    MessageBox.Show("Você digitou: " + textBoxTemp.Text);
}
```

Você tem certeza absoluta que `sender` é do tipo `TextBox`? Como eu conheço o padrão do Windows Forms que você está usando eu diria que sim, é. Portanto esta "conversão" não falhará, é certo que ela é possível. Qualquer situação que você saberá que ela não falhará você pode usá-lo. Em muitos casos o custo é zero.

Mas vou reforçar que você tem que ter certeza, nem sempre é possível garantir isto.

Saiba que se houver um erro na tentativa de conversão a aplicação lançará uma exceção e possivelmente quebrar. E isto é bom. Era um erro de programação em algum lugar mesmo. Você deve consertar o erro. [Não deve capturar a exceção e tentar arrumar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21939/101). Erros de programação devem ser resolvidos pelo programador, não pelo código. Uma das soluções possíveis é não usar o operador de *cast* desta forma.

## Operador `as`

É aí que entra o operador `as`. O uso dele implica que você não tem muita certeza que a operação vai dar certo. Então podemos considerar que ele trabalha como uma tentativa e se falhar o objeto que deveria receber a "conversão" receberá o valor nulo. Por isso sempre depois de usar o `as` é preciso verificar se o objeto não é nulo. Então você faria:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    TextBox textBoxTemp = sender as TextBox;
    if (textBoxTemp != null) {
        MessageBox.Show("Você digitou: " + textBoxTemp.Text);
    }
}
```

#### Operador *null-propagating*

No C# 6 você pode optar por este código:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    TextBox textBoxTemp = sender as TextBox;
    MessageBox.Show("Você digitou: " + textBoxTemp?.Text);
}
```

Não que o resultado seja o mesmo, mas se você apenas não quer que dê erro, pode ser uma boa opção. Não parece ser o caso neste exemplo já que ele mostrará a mensagem "Você digitou: " e mais nada, não vai indicar problema, nada.

O custo do operador `as` mais a verificação se a operação foi bem sucedida costuma ser o mesmo do uso do *cast* na maioria das situações. E quando há diferença não é nada absurdo. De qualquer forma você deve usar o que for o correto para a situação.

O `as` não consegue fazer conversões em tipos por valor diretamente já que eles não podem ter resultado nulo. Porém é possível usar um tipo anulável para obter o mesmo resultado.

Ele também não consegue fazer conversões definidas pelo usuário (mesmo aquelas definidas dentro do .NET), apenas conversões definidas pela linguagem são possíveis. Esta conversões normalmente exigem algum processamento e só podem ser feitas com o *cast* tradicional.

## Erro comum

Não cometa exageros como fazer isto:

```
if (sender is TextBox) {
    TextBox sender = (TextBox) textBoxTemp;
    //faz algo aqui
}
```

É comum ver isto em alguns código para "evitar" o lançamento da exceção. Está errado. Este código está comparando se o tipo é compatível uma vez no `if` e depois compara de novo dentro do *cast*.

Pior, em alguns casos pode haver uma [*race condition*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101) já que entre a primeira verificação e a conversão efetiva o estado do objeto pode ter mudado.

## *Pattern matching*

Em C# 7 é possível criar a variável condicionalmente com *pattern matching* sem precisar do *cast*:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (textBoxTemp isTextBox textBoxTemp) {
        MessageBox.Show("Você digitou: " + textBoxTemp.Text);
    }
}
```

## Conclusão

Note que os operadores têm semânticas diferentes, eles são usados para situações diferentes. Quando for usar um ou outro deve fazer você pensar no *design* da aplicação, você deve entender porque está usando um ou outro. Não é só uma escolha do que funciona ou não.

Resposta parcialmente inspirada [nessa resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/496167/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Cast/CastWays.cs).

Comment: Não entendi seu exemplo de "não cometa exageros", está correto o exemplo? O que você quer dizer com ele? Me parece que confundiu algumas variáveis? Ou não?

Comment: @Fernando ainda não terminei de editar a resposta, vou melhorar esta parte.

Comment: Ok, é que achei estranho. Irei aguardar, sem ansiedade. hehe

Comment: Algo intrigante aqui: você, baseado na resposta que citou, comentou que `if (sender is TextBox)` seria um erro, enquanto a msdn, conforme coloquei na minha resposta, diz que o operador `as` é equivalente a `expression is type ? (type)expression : (type)null`, ou seja, que faz justamente uma comparação, embora a expressão seja calculada apenas uma vez. Estou perdendo alguma coisa?

Comment: @Fernando melhorei, tem 2 coisas que não gosto na sua resposta: capturar exceção que no fundo é erro de programação. Você até parece reconhecer isto pelo comentário no código. Deu erro, arruma. Aconteceu em produção? Deve "logar" o erro e quebrar mesmo. E isto pode ser feito por um capturador global da aplicação não precisa fazer em cada código que pode dar erro.. A outra coisa é verificar antes de converter porque pode causar uma *race condition*.

Comment: @iuristona primeiro a documentação da MSDN tá cheio de furos e exemplos péssimos que fazem as pessoas programarem de forma terrível. Mas nem é o caso neste ponto específico. O primeiro problema de fazer o `if` com `is` é justamente o que eu falei, repetir o que o `as`vai fazer. Pra que repetir? Então fui consistente. O segundo problema é que entre o seu `if` e este ternário que faz a mesma coisa, o estado do objeto pode mudar. Então você está confiando em uma informação que pode ser falsa. O certo é tente fazer e verifique se deu certo. Isto vale para tantas coisas em programação...

Comment: Não, não me referi a não usar o `as`, ou fazer diferente. Apenas que fiquei intrigado com o fato de o [msdn][1] citar  a equivalência `as` pro ternário com is, e que eu cheguei a supor, seria mais uma sintax suggar. Depois da tua resposta, removi a minha. [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @bigown Estou tentando compreender como a alteração do estado do objeto afeta a sua conversão. E no caso de realmente afetar, qual é a diferença, numa condição de concorrência, entre o estado do objeto afetar esta conversão e afetar qualquer outro trabalho sobre este objeto? Digo, qual a diferença entre a situação de concorrência afetar `if (objeto is Classe) then Classe x = (Classe)objeto;` e afetar `if (objeto.saldo > 0) then enviaCobranca();`? Ou seja, mesmo que a situação de concorrência afete, não é um problema especial que seja diferente de qualquer outro trazido pelo concorrência. Ou é?

Comment: Não é diferente, por isto mesmo esta situação deve ser tratada da mesma forma, com o cuidado de não pegar um objeto em transição. Realmente não tem diferença entre os dois exemplos, o segundo também está errado estritamente falando. É claro que a consequência dele não será quebrar a aplicação, apenas enviar cobrança indevida. Deve ser por sistemas assim que sempre vem a mensagem para ignorar a cobrança se já foi pago :D Em um caso concreto pode-se até avaliar se esta condição conflituosa não causará problema real e usar sem problemas. Mas é algo a mais para se preocupar e ainda será redundante

Comment: @bigown Bem, o aviso na cobrança é porque você pode estar pagando a conta enquanto o envelope é impresso ou enquanto o email trafega pela internet - nada de errado com o sistema, creio. De qualquer modo permanece ainda uma dúvida: como o estado do objeto pode afetar a sua conversão através de cast?

Comment: Não foi eu que criei o operador de *cast* daquele tipo, tantas coisas podem dar errado dentro dele dependendo do seu estado. Eu sei que eu não posso confiar em algo que não é garantido pela linguagem. Se ainda tiver dúvidas ou quiser mais detalhes você pode perguntar para o Jon Skeet, ele entende de C# pelo menos 10 vezes mais que eu.

Comment: Ah, entendi! Você apenas reproduziu a observação feita na resposta linkada do Jon Skeet. Acabei de ler lá. Ele não fala sobre mudança do estado do objeto mas sim a mudança do valor da própria variável. É lógico que se o ojeto referenciado pela variável for de um tipo compatível e depois não for mais, o cast vai falhar - nenhum mistério. O único mistério que permanece é por que ele foi falar sobre o efeito de um design multithreading ruim numa questão sobre casting. Então 50% das respostas teriam que receber um parágrafo a mais para tratar a possível influência de um design ruim no código.

Comment: Eu gosto do estilo dele e do Eric Lippert de responder o máximo que der para mostrar tudo o pode influenciar naquilo que foi perguntado. Sempre que eu estou com paciência eu adiciono detalhes adicionais.

Comment: @bigown, concordo em parte com você, quando digo em parte é porque, ao dizer "Aconteceu em produção? Deve "logar" o erro e quebrar mesmo", nem sempre quebrar mesmo é viável, mesmo que seja um erro de programação, em ambiente WinForms, acredito que até seria, mas WebService ou Serviços, isso já não é mas tão verdade, já que pode, falei PODE, comprometer todo um serviço.

Comment: @bigown, e também não sei você já teve oportunidade de conhecer melhor as novas plataformas windows 8, que se você cria um serviço que irá executar em background, como por exemplo uma rotina agendada para atualização de um Tile do Windows Phone 8 ou Windows 8, se sua rotina falhar 2 (ou 3, não lembro, não encontrei a fonte que vi isso, mas foi no msdn) ela será automaticamente desagendada, o que não é nada bom.

Comment: @bigown, já a respeito de "A outra coisa é verificar antes de converter porque pode causar uma race condition", sim entendi e é bem verdade que isso pode acontecer, mas citei isso em minha resposta pois, se você faz um "capturador" de eventos que, por exemplo, pode vir de um Button ou de um TextBox, então acredito que checar qual antes de converte no minimo é mais elegante.

Comment: Tentar continuar executando algo que deu errado provavelmente vai comprometer muito mais. Se é serviço, reinicie ele. Não tente se recuperar. Claro que reiniciar um serviço que está errado não é o ideal mas nem sempre é possível aplicar o ideal. Pelo menos ele começa em estado limpo. É mais próximo do ideal. Querer contornar uma limitação criada justamente para proteger o sistema de coisas ruins é a pior coisa que alguém deve fazer. De qualquer forma porque em erro de programação foi para produção? Isto deveria acontecer uma vez por século. O problema é outro.

Answer (score 3):

Um lança Exception, e o outro somente retorna null, caso falhem.

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBoxTemp = (TextBox)sender; // se por algum acaso, o objeto sender, não for do tipo TextBox, você terá um InvalidCastException
    MessageBox.Show("Você digitou: " + textBoxTemp.Text);
}

private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBoxTemp = sender as TextBox; // já aqui, se por algum acaso, o objeto sender, não for do tipo TextBox, ele só retorna um objeto null.
    MessageBox.Show("Você digitou: " + textBoxTemp.Text); // então aqui sim lançaria uma NullPointerException
}
```

Já as forma de tratamento para evitar `Exception` é muito mais eficiente e simples com `as`, do com `Cast`, como demonstrado abaixo:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // com try catch, é não é eficiente para tratar dados
    try
    {
        TextBox textBoxTemp = (TextBox)sender; // se por algum acaso, o objeto sender, não for do tipo TextBox, você terá um InvalidCastException
        MessageBox.Show("Você digitou: " + textBoxTemp.Text);
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException ex)
    {
        //Ou simplismente sem nada, "padrão Silenciator" (um grande designer pattern, hehe)
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBoxTemp = sender as TextBox; // já aqui, se por algum acaso, o objeto sender, não for do tipo TextBox, ele só retorna um objeto null.
    // com uma simples verificação de referencia diferente de null
    if (textBoxTemp != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Você digitou: " + textBoxTemp.Text);
    }
}
```

Você também pode utilizar a instrução [`is`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx), que faz uma verificação de tipagem, para depois converter para o tipo correto. E também é bem util se você está esperando alguns tipos diferente como por exemplo:

```
if (sender is TextBox)
{
    TextBox textBoxTemp = sender as TextBox;
} else if (sender is Button)
{
    Button buttonTemp = sender as Button;
}
// e pode ter outras verificações
```

Com `is` é a maneira como geralmente utilizo. Por me parecer mais agradável.

Answer (score 0):

O `cast` lança `Exception` se o objeto não for do tipo e o `as` somente retorna `null`.