# Exibir casas decimais (Currency) está arredondando

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, decimal

Tenho uma aplicação onde o preço deve ir em formato `int` sem casas decimais.

```
int Valor = (int)(produto.Valor * 100); //o produto.Valor é um decimal
```

**O problema está quando quero exibir esse valor na View**

No caso de produtos como  0,10 ele exibe 0

```
int Valor = (int)(produto.Valor * 100);
```

**o Valor fica 10, equivalente a 0,10 (perfeito até aqui)**

Tentei:

```
@{
decimal Valor = Model.ValorExibicao / 100; //ValorExibicao é um int
}
@Valor.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-br"))
```

Exibe R$ 0,00

Tentei:

```
@Convert.ToDouble(Model.ValorExibicao/ 100);
```

Exibe `0`
Somente `@Model.ValorExibicao` mostra o correto 10 (equivalente a 0,10)

Poderia criar na *viewModel* o valor correto sem formatação, porém acho que seria uma gambiarra para contornar um erro meu.

Comment: Não será porque valor é declarado como um int? Quando você "casteia" o decimal para um int, ele vai perder a parte decimal. Se era 0,10, ficará 0 mesmo. Não use int para essas operações, trabalhe direto com decimal.

Comment: mas o sistema (Cielo) pede o preço em int.
Por isso que para converter eu divido por 100 e em teoria voltaria a ter casa decimal no caso double, float, decimal...

Comment: Já tentou @Convert.ToDouble(Model.ValorExibicao/ 100.0);

Comment: @Dorathoto, preço em int creio que não deveria existir. Valores são centavos(divididos por 100) e quase sempre terá o valor com casas  decimais. Não faz sentido ter número inteiro para representar um valor divido por 100(casas decimais).

Comment: @pnet, sempre uso preço em decimal, porem o sistema de 3º está pedindo em formato int. A dúvida não era se devo armazenar em int ou decimal.

Comment: @RafaelFerreira coloca como resposta que agora foi, parabéns

Comment: @Dorathoto conversão para `double` vai dar problema, por isso que tem que entender como as coisas funcionam e não confiar no teste básico que faz, tem valor que dá certo, tem valor que não dá, vai deixar seu sistema assim? Na verdade eu não entendi seu problema, muito menos porque uma divisão soluciona o problema. Se você quer que um valor com centavos deva ficar inteira (escalar para cima) o correto é a multiplicação.

Comment: @bigown na verdade é um campo que vou exbir para o cliente, ao enviar o valor para o sistema de terceiros preciso enviar ele inteiro, ex: R$ 25,36 = 2536 para isso eu peguei o meu valor decimal e multipliquei por 100, até ai perfeito, o problema é agora que quero exibir para o cliente o valor, sem ter que recuperar de novo do database, ou ter que criar um novo campo na viewmodel só pra isso, pensei em dividir por 100 e voltar ao valor original, porém não conseguia.

Comment: @Dorathoto `Model.ValorExibicao` é um `decimal` ou `int`? Acho que estou começando entender, você fez o primeiro cálculo no *model*, e aí o valor fica errado na *view*?

Comment: Model.ValorExibicao é um int...

Comment: A resposta não deveria ser do @RafaelFerreira? Só li o seu comentário.

Comment: sim, mas o @RafaelFerreira não colocou resposta, apenas comentário, não tem como marcar válido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução é bem simples:

```
Model.ValorExibicao / 100M
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Decimal/Division2.cs).

Isto garante que a divisão será feita em decimal, já que o sufixo `M` indica um literal decimal. Aí se quiser aplicar um `ToString()`, um `string.Format()`, ou uma [*string* interpolada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91117/101), ou outra forma para formatar a exibição, as casas decimais, fica a seu critério, o cálculo estará certo desta forma.

[Nunca use `double` para valores monetários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101) ou outros que não possa ter problemas de arredondamento.

Answer (score 4):

Existe outras formas de se obter o mesmo resultado, como tudo na programação. Você pode fazer um [Cast explícito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47935/20615) para `decimal`. Utilizar o [decimal.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cafs243z(v=vs.110).aspx) para converter os valores (muito usado quando o valor está em `string`). Pode também usar o [Convert.ToDecimal()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9k6z9cdw(v=vs.110).aspx). Essas três opções irão lhe retornar o valor inteiro com casas decimais.

Abaixo deixarei um exemplo de como utilizar cada uma das formas citadas acima:

```
public static void Main()
{
    int valor = 10;
    string valorString = "10";

    decimal valorNormal = valor/100;

    decimal valorCast = (decimal)valor/100;

    decimal valorParse = decimal.Parse(valorString)/100;

    decimal valorConvert = Convert.ToDecimal(valor)/100;

    Console.WriteLine("Valor Normal: " + valorNormal);
    Console.WriteLine("Cast explítico: " + valorCast);
    Console.WriteLine("Parse: " + valorParse);
    Console.WriteLine("Converto to: " + valorConvert);

}
```

[Exemplo funcionando no dotNetFiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mYNu5W)