# Como obter atributo de um objeto de tipo genérico?

Tags: c#, .net, genéricos

Estou com dificuldades p/ recuperar um objeto para obter um atributo específico.

Quero sobrescrever o método `Equals` em minha classe, para comparar se o título dos objetos são idênticos. Nesse caso, não tem importância se o tipo e os outros atributos são diferentes. Só quero comparar se o atributo `Title` de ambos são iguais.

Meu código está assim:

```csharp
namespace Kitty.Core.Blocks
{
    class Block<T>
    {
        public string Title { get; private set; }
        public T Contents { get; private set; }

        public Block(string title, T contents)
        {
            this.Title = title;
            this.Contents = contents;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            Block<?> other = obj; // ?



            return string.Equals(this.Title, other.Title);
        }
    }
}
```

O problema está nesse trecho:

```csharp
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Block<?> other = obj; // Como recupero "obj"?


    return string.Equals(this.Title, other.Title);
}
```

Tentei assim:

```csharp
Block<?> other = (Block<?>) obj;
```

E assim:

```csharp
Block other = (Block) obj;
```

Mas sou forçado a especificar o tipo:

> Using the generic type '`Block<T>`' requires 1 type arguments.

Como estou sobrescrevendo, não adianta mudar a assinatura do método e trocar `object` pelo mesmo nome da classe.

Então, como posso recupera esse `obj`, mantendo o tipo genérico dele (que não sei qual será) para comparar somente o atributo `Title` de ambos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não sei se tem algum objetivo que eu não entendi, mas é só colocar o genérico normal e tratar o objeto como se fosse do tipo que quer. Se não for, ele receberá um `null`e precisa tratar isto:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    Block<T> other = obj as Block<T>;
    if (other == null) return false;
    return Title == other.Title;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BKOrVC). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KYRhxe). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/GetField.cs).

Obviamente que tem outras formas de realizar o mesmo.

Note que você não pode comparar um `Block<string>` com um `Block<List<string>>` e esperar que eles sejam iguais. Se até o tipo do objeto é diferente, não há como ser igual. Quando tentar fazer um *cast* no objeto recebido, vai falhar e o resultado será nulo, afinal você não pode transformar um `Block<List<string>>` em um `Block<string>`, eles são estruturalmente diferentes. Mesmo que tivesse um campo (`Title`) igual, o outro não é nem do mesmo tipo. Só pode dar `false`.

Poderia querer lançar uma exceção no lugar de retornar um `false`. Não gosto dessa solução, ela seria menos idiomática do que no Java (que abusa de exceções).

[Poderia usar um *cast* normal (`(tipo)`)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47935/101) mas ele poderia gerar uma exceção, não acho que seja o desejável. O *cast* simples só deveria ser usado quando você tem certeza que ele não falhará, o que não é o caso. Mesmo que prefira ele, o que considero um erro, e que prefira que este método lance uma exceção, o que também acho inadequado, a exceção deveria ser outra, então seria melhor capturar a exceção do *cast* e lançar uma de [`ArgumentException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentexception?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Algumas considerações:

- Em C# o que está sendo chamado de [atributo normalmente é chamado de campo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75265/101), já que atributo é o nome de outro mecanismo da linguagem.
- Em C# é mais raro o abuso da separação do *namespace*, que já é algo bem diferente dos pacotes do Java. Cada ponto cria um novo *namespace* e normalmente só se cria um novo quando ele efetivamente é usado e faz sentido, não se costuma usar o ponto só para separar a palavra.
- Quando se cria um `Equals()` especializado, quase sempre deseja-se criar um `GetHashCode()` especializado também.
- Muito provavelmente seria melhor criar também (ou só) o operador de igualdade (`==`). Em C# o método `Equals()` não é tão usado, já que a linguagem permite ter operadores especializados. Isso pode ser observado no exemplo que eu fiz preferindo o operador no lugar do método.

Comment: É isso mesmo, estava lendo sobre `IEquatable` mas nem será preciso, não conhecia o `as`. Sobre *namespace*, você quis dizer que, ao invés de `namespace Kitty.Core.Blocks` seria somente `namespace Blocks`?

Comment: Poderia, ou poderia ser `KittyCoreBlocks`. Note que não estou dizendo que não possa usar com os pontos, ou mesmo que não deva se fizer mais sentido. Depende do que você quer. Pode ser que precise de uma separação clara, eu não tenho como saber isto. É só uma questão semântica do código, não muda nada pra linguagem. O que que quero dizer que o Java "ensina" o programador encher de ponto no nome dos pacotes e o C# incentiva evitar isto a não ser que tenha um motivo. Por exemplo isto é uma excrecência em C#: `br.org.empresa.produto.alguma.coisa`. Não o ponto como se fosse espaço ou *underline*.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas recomendações. Sobre a resposta: eu testei com títulos iguais porém usando um tipo diferente de `string`, o resultado foi `false`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JgY1H6 Faltou eu fazer algo?

Comment: E este comportamento me parece correto, não? Aí tem duas questões. O teste de igualdade de uma lista, seja pelo operador, seja pelo método ´Equals()`, vai testar se a referência é a mesma e não se o conteúdo é igual. Se precisa de outro comportamento, é um problema do objeto usado e não desta classe. Se não pode aceitar isto teria que fazer uma restrição nos tipos que ´T` pode aceitar (com `where`) ou mesmo barrar com um `if` (não é o ideal, mas tem caso que não tem muito jeito). No exemplo você comparou uma *string* com uma lista. É tão diferente (até o tipo). Você espera que dê `true`?

Comment: Então, mas eu comparei somente o campo `Title`, que de ambos é uma string, não é isso? O que eu estou tentando fazer é: comparar somente o campo `Title` de ambos, o tipo do `<T>` não tem importância nessa comparação. Por exemplo: `title: foo, contents: string` seria igual a `title: foo, contents: lista de string`. É possível fazer isso no próprio `Equals` ou eu teria que recuperar o titulo de cada bloco posteriormente e fazer a comparação por `if(bloco1.Title == bloco2.Title){}`?

Comment: É verdade. Na verdade percebi que tem um problema no algoritmo que eu nem tinha questionado, me ative ao código querendo fazer o que queria. Se a comparação é sempre com o `Title` e ele é sempre `string`, esse *cast* para `Block<T>` não faz sentido. Teria que ser para `string`. Se eu entendi bem é a única mudança necessária, se me conformar posso mudar isto (ainda que descaracterize a intenção original da pergunta).

Comment: É que estou aprendendo c# agora e talvez esteja confuso sobre como perguntar. Eu gostaria de uma solução para isso, se possível :)

Comment: Na verdade até escrevi uma besteira aí no comentário. Mas vou editar a resposta para mostrar que este comportamento parece ser o correto. Não faz sentido sobre a lista ser diferente, porque não compara listas, o *cast* também precisa ser feito pq é feito no objeto e não no campo. Funciona se o tipo for o mesmo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cMB4AZ

Comment: Acho que entendi o motivo de não funcionar. É que o meu método em Java está [escrito assim](http://pastebin.com/upFcQ8zh). Pensei que fosse possível fazer algo semelhante em C#.

Comment: Não sei se entendi. Os códigos não estavam equivalentes. Mas o que eu fiz deixou equivalente. Pelo menos eu acho, pelo que entendi o seu daria o mesmo resultado que o meu, afinal se o tipo genérico for diferente, você está dizendo pra retornar `false` explicitamente. No C# não precisa porque o *cast*  com `as` falhando não vai gerar exceção. Mas se quiser fazer um port idêntico ao Java, pode fazer (está escrito na resposta), só acho uma solução menos elegante.É interessante colocar a verificação do `null` no código do C# também.Se passar 1 nulo para o método,vai dar exceção igual ao Java faria

Comment: Realmente o problema era que eu estava checando tipos diferentes, foi mal por ter tomado seu tempo. Tinha visto a classe de testes errada em Java, por isso eu estava tentando fazer essa loucura de comparar objetos diferentes.

Comment: De jeito nenhum. Todos aprendemos alguma coisa aqui.